# Java Generics: how can i assign a method's return value which uses multiple inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inferred-type

I have a method which returns a complex generic type (which implements multiple interfaces)

```
protected abstract <BOB extends Stan & Jan<I>> BOB getStanAndJanItem();
```

This compiles fine, and i'm able to override it and return values.  As soon as i call it i get compilation errors though (it doesn't even have to be assigned to anything).  And i guess this makes sense, since BOB is only defined inside the method.

So, how do i define bob at a class level?

And YES, I know i can just split up the calls and have them return the same object, or introduce some additional inheritance (and i'll probably end up doing that) but can it be done this way as well?

**Error Received:**
  *Bound mismatch: The generic method getStanAndJanItem() of type `MyAbstractClass<I>` is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type Stan is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<BOB extends Stan & Jan<I>>`*

Comment: It sounds like you're misusing generics.

Comment: Can you post exactly how you are calling the method?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the method, you need to pass a generic type parameter that matches your constraint.
Even if your particular call doesn't need it, you still need to pass the type parameter.

Therefore, you can only call the method if you parameterize it with some class or interface that implements both of those types.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that would look like.  I'm trying to duplicate code like   - protected static <T extends Jan<I> & Stan> void do( T janAndStan, int id)  - which works fine as a parameter

Comment: @rediVider: `something. <X> getStanAndJanItem()`, where `X` implements both interfaces.

Comment: i got 'The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable' when trying to assigne it to <T extends Stan & Jan<I>> T bob, or <T extends Stan & Jan<I>> bob

Comment: `<T extends Stan & Jan<I>>` is not a type that you can use to declare a variable.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder if the use of 'var' in .Net is a workaround for this.  Thanks much for the quick responses.  Guess i'll continue with adding an abstract descendent of the two interfaces

Comment: No, it isn't.  You cannot use generics to create new types in either language.  You must always call a generic method with a concrete type as the generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is the lack of support of *intersection type*. Suppose language support it directly, we can write intersection type like `A&B` etc, and your example would be like

```
Stan&Jan<I> getStanAndJanItem()

void setStanAndJanItem(Stan&Jan<I> item)


Stan&Jan<I> result = getStanAndJanItem();
result.doStanStuff();
result.doJanStuff();

setStanAndJanItem(result);
```

Without such support, we are stuck. Your generic declaration is probably wrong: it implies that the caller decides the `BOB` type, while you probably want the implementation to decide the `BOB` type. The implementation can return anything that implements both `Stan` and `Jan<I>`. Currently, that requirement cannot be expressed.

Comment: As i noted in response to SLaks, I have a method which can impose generic contraints on its parameters  [e.g.  protected static <T extends Jan<I> & Stan> void do( T janAndStan, int id) ].  I was just hoping to extend this to a return type.  It seems to me that the same mechanism would work in this case as well, but alas...I appear to be wrong.